# "did you" or "do you" if I'm asking about what language that's s(he) learn?

Tags: difference, tense

If I'm asking other people what language that's S(he) learn, which sentence should I use?

> What language did you learn?

or

> What language do you learn?

Which is more grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the context. If you are asking what language s(he) learned (in the past), you must use the first one. If you are asking what language s(he) is learning in the present, you must use one of these sentences:

> What language are you learning?

or

> What language are you studying?

Comment: thank you for answering!